# Separating positive and negative values of pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to separately sum all positive and negative values in a column ie

```
pos_values = [x for x in df.prediction_at_ohlcv_end_date if x > 0] 
neg_values = [x for x in df.prediction_at_ohlcv_end_date if x < 0]
```

Here's a data sample

```
market_trading_pair next_future_timestep_return ohlcv_start_date    prediction_at_ohlcv_end_date
0   Poloniex_ETH_BTC    0.003013    1450753200  -0.157053
1   Poloniex_ETH_BTC    -0.006521   1450756800  -0.920074
2   Poloniex_ETH_BTC    0.003171    1450760400  0.999806
3   Poloniex_ETH_BTC    -0.003083   1450764000  0.627140
4   Poloniex_ETH_BTC    -0.001382   1450767600  0.999857
```

What's a nice way to do this in pandas ?

EDIT:

I have been able to do this thanks to some helpful stackers, I realised I can't a futher calculation however. `

```
if prediction_at_ohlcv_end_date > 0 : 
return = prediction_at_ohlcv_end_date * next_future_timestep_return.
```

For each element in the frame, Any ideas?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use method [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) of `pandas.Series` for your particular column:

```
neg = df.prediction_at_ohlcv_end_date[df.prediction_at_ohlcv_end_date < 0].sum()
pos = df.prediction_at_ohlcv_end_date[df.prediction_at_ohlcv_end_date >= 0].sum()

In [51]: pos
Out[51]: 2.6268029999999998

In [52]: neg
Out[52]: -1.077127
```

For your values:

```
pos_values = df.prediction_at_ohlcv_end_date[df.prediction_at_ohlcv_end_date >= 0]
neg_values = df.prediction_at_ohlcv_end_date[df.prediction_at_ohlcv_end_date < 0]
```

**EDIT**

For your edit you could do:

```
mask = df.prediction_at_ohlcv_end_date >= 0
res = df.prediction_at_ohlcv_end_date[mask] * df.next_future_timestep_return[mask]

In [10]: res
Out[10]: 
2    0.003170
3   -0.001933
4   -0.001382
dtype: float64
```

Comment: You can also use `query` to shorten the commands a bit: `pos = df.query('prediction_at_ohlcv_end_date > 0').sum()`

Comment: Hey, thanks alot. Really big help. It seem i forgot one more operation i need to do, any chance you could look at my edit ?